# Synax error print [python]

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am having trouble with my code, When I run this i get a syntax error 'print'

```
word1 = input("Words: ")
characters = len(word1)
listOfStuff = str(word1)
strip = ""
x = 1
while not characters > 140 - 11:
    word = input("Words: ")
    if characters <= 140 - 11:
        listOfStuff = listOfStuff + ' ' + str(word)
        characters = characters + len(word) - 1
    elif characters > 140 - 11:
        strip = len(word)
        break
finalLength = len(listOfStuff)
print(listOfStuff.rstrip(strip)
print(finalLength)
```

when am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use vim and type `:DoMatchParen`

Answer (score 5):

You missed a closing parenthesis:

```
print(listOfStuff.rstrip(strip)
#                      --------^
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

**Python2.x**

1) You may want to use

```
raw_input("Words: ")
```

instead of

```
input("Words: ")
```

2) `print` doesn't expect parenthesis

```
print listOfStuff.rstrip(strip)
print finalLength
```

**Python3**

1) Martijn Pieters's anwer holds good. You are missing a closing parenthesis

```
print(listOfStuff.rstrip(strip))
```

instead of

```
print(listOfStuff.rstrip(strip)
```

Comment: In the case of Python2, the parentheses don't hurt, so it is ok to leave them (at least if I only print one item).